# block placement with raycast in unity3d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, raycasting

I'm trying a game like Space Engineers/Minecraft.
with this code, I place a block on the side of a block already placed using raycast. It works well until I add a collider(then it place the block anywhere between block and screen). Help with code or another idea, please.

```
RaycastHit hit;
int maxBuildDist = 10;
public GameObject Block;
Vector3 BlockPos;
```

void Update(){

```
if(Physics.Raycast(Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(                                                
    new Vector3((Screen.width / 2 ),(Screen.height / 2),0)),out hit, maxBuildDist)){

        BlockPos = new Vector3(hit.normal.x,hit.normal.y,hit.normal.z);  

        Block.transform.position = (hit.transform.position + BlockPos)/2;                         
    }
}
```

}

Comment: sorry this line Block.transform.position = (hit.point + BlockPos)/2; is actualy Block.transform.position = (hit.transform.position + BlockPos)/2;

Answer (score 2):

Update your `Physics.Raycast` call to only hit the objects you're interested in. Check the `Physics.Raycast` documentation about the `layerMask` parameter to learn how to do this: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.Raycast.html

## 1. Create a layer, and set on block prefab

Use the dropdown menu in the prefab's Inspector window:

[image: Dropdown menu in top-right of Inspector window highlighted]

## 2. Update call to Physics.Raycast

Say you created a new layer named "BlockLayer". You would change your `Update` function to this:

```cs
// Find the layer based on its name.
var layerId = LayerMask.NameToLayer("BlockLayer");

// Set our mask to "ignore everything except for blocks".
var layerMask = ~layerId;

// Update the Physics.Raycast call - pass in the layer mask
if(Physics.Raycast(
  Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(new Vector3((Screen.width / 2 ),(Screen.height / 2),0)),
  out hit,
  maxBuildDist,
  layerMask))
{
    // This code will only be reached if the raycast hit a block.
    BlockPos = new Vector3(hit.normal.x,hit.normal.y,hit.normal.z);  
    Block.transform.position = (hit.transform.position + BlockPos)/2;                         
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the Quick reply but var layerMask = ~layerId;(= Ignore this layer) must be replaced by int layerMask = 1 << 8;(ignore all but this layer)  now it works Thank you.

Comment: The simplest way is actually to simply make a `[SerializeField] private LayerMask layerMask;` instead where you can simply configure the layers you want to hit from a dropdown list using the Unity Inspector. It is then implicitely converted into the according `int` value